# Can you get a free copy of Minecraft Pocket Edition if you have Legacy edition?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-legacy-console

I am in a group project where everyone but one member has MCPE. They have an Xbox account, have paid for the Console game and need it.

Answer (score 1):

If you buy the Legacy version of Minecraft, you should be able to get Minecraft Bedrock edition for free by going to the Xbox Store.